# Dockerfile for cloning private git repo

Tags: ssh, docker

I'm trying to clone private git repository from github. I did a Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:12.04

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y git
RUN mkdir -p /root/.ssh/
ADD ./id_rsa /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN git clone git@github.com:usr/repo.git
```

I use this repo with this key just fine locally, so it seems I'm missing something inside docker.

One more thing I may be missing is that both `~` and `$HOME` inside docker point to `/` instead of `/root`, but I'm not sure if that can be related.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

What's the output of the build process?

Random guess: try to `chmod 600` the private key.

If it still doesn't work, try to `RUN ssh -v git@github.com` (after adding the key); the output should explain what's happening.

Comment: Thank you. The problem was that it couldn't open tty to ask me about "known_hosts" yes/no. `-v` for showing debug info is a great advice.

Comment: How did you actually solve it? By adding the host to known_hosts in the Dockerfile?

Comment: One possibility would be to use `ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts`, yes! Or do a first login attempt with `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no` (which will result in the same thing, but will be idempotent).

Comment: I don't understand the Dockerfile build process very well, but is every step completed in a different container?     
`docker build --rm=false -t peterbecich/parkinsons .`
  ...
  ``Step 13 : RUN eval `ssh-agent -s`
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 685501debd36``
  ...
  `Step 14 : RUN ssh-add /root/.ssh/pdl_resources_for_docker
 ---> Running in daee32024ba9
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.`

    `ssh-add` tries to find the agent, which is in a different container.  So it fails.

Comment: Figured it out.  This seems to be the reason people fit commands into one Dockerfile RUN line: `RUN eval "$(ssh-agent)" && ssh-agent -s`

Answer (score 17):

RUN ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts

The keyscan works great since it accepts the host. The following complete answer worked:

```
RUN mkdir -p /root/.ssh
RUN cp /var/my-app/id_rsa /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN ssh-keyscan github.com >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Also as mentioned:

```
RUN ssh -v git@github.com
```

^ Great way to debug the flow. That's how I realized I needed the keyscan >> known_hosts

Answer (score 2):

(Will probably not fit your needs)

There is another approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29464430/990356

Go to [Settings > Personal access tokens](https://github.com/settings/tokens) and generate a personal access token with `repo` scope enabled.
Now you can do `git clone https://MY_TOKEN@github.com/user-or-org/repo`

Pros:

- very simple approach
- token can be easily revoked

Cons:

- if someone has access to the Dockerfile he has access to the token

To fix this, you can use an environment variable to store the token

Answer (score 1):

Below approach is using `https` with [Personal Access Token](https://github.com/settings/tokens), and it works like charm.

```
ARG git_personal_token
RUN git config --global url."https://${git_personal_token}:@github.com/".insteadOf "https://github.com/"
RUN git clone https://github.com/your/project.git /project
```

Then, supply a docker argument as below.

```
docker build --build-arg git_personal_token={your_token} .
```

Basic idea is from https://medium.com/paperchain/fetching-private-github-repos-from-a-docker-container-273f25ec5a74