# Why can't I git clone a private git repository with the correct ssh keys in docker?

Tags: git, docker, github, ssh

I am trying to `git clone` from inside a docker container to a private repository using ssh authentication. I followed a solution presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23391839/clone-private-git-repo-with-dockerfile).

To do so, I created a local key

```
ssh-keygen -q -t rsa -N '' -f repo-key
```

and added the public key to the `github` ssh keys. Then in the Dockerfile I added:

```
RUN chmod 600 repo-key && \  
    echo "IdentityFile /selenium/repo-key" >> /etc/ssh/ssh_config && \  
    echo "StrictHostKeyChecking no" >> /etc/ssh/ssh_config
```

But when I try to `git clone` a repository I got the error message

```
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Anything else I can check to make this work?

Again to explain the WHY: I want to be able to create images with a FIXED private key which ALWAYS works with the public key at github, so I can use the SAME image, but able to download the actual/current repository into the running container. The image is equipped with the correct keys, so it has access to the github repository and able to download the current repository when a contained is started from the same image...
The image is for selenium tests, which will later executed automatically by a script (or jenkins), and then I am not able to 'log in' to the container to create a ssk key pair and upload the public key to github. The whole thing is to automate the testing. Therefore, the authentification has to be build into the image.

HOPEFULLY this is clear now.

Comment: Have you tried what is being discussed here: [Clone private git repo with dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23391839/clone-private-git-repo-with-dockerfile)?

Comment: Oh thanks for this link; I actually built my solution on exactly the solution presented in there...

Comment: I've noticed a small difference in your `git clone ssh:// ...` command. Have you tried with what is being mentioned there (`git clone git@...`)?

Comment: No, as `git clone ssh...` is - as far as I know - the correct command to authenticate via ssh.. Thats the whole point...

Comment: Can you also try what @jpetazzo proposes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19643946/dockerfile-for-cloning-private-git-repo?noredirect=1&lq=1) for debugging?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already creating a ssh key inside your docker container. What you need to do:

- Login into docker container to copy the generated ssh public key.
- You need to then add the public key to your github account.

After that you can easily clone the private git repo.

Comment: I want to do this without logging in. I want to create a docker image automatically and ready to use.

Comment: @Raza Mehdi, the OP wants to add the key in the `image` not a (later created) `container`.

Comment: @tgogos I know that. He is cloning a repo through ssh. There is a manual step involved which includes adding a ssh key to github, unless there is a configured program which automatically a ssh public key to github

Comment: I have already added the public key to github. For the image creation I want to use the corresponding private key in the image

Comment: @Alex Every time you create an image the corresponding ssh key that is generated will be different every time.

Comment: Not when I use a key somewhere stored on the host computer. I cannot use a new key every time, it would be stupid to manually insert a new public key every time to github...

Comment: What you are doing is that you are copying the key inside a container. What Github is doing is trying to validate your key against a container not your host. That's why you are getting permission denied error.

Comment: Yes, and my question is how to solve it? Because I have THE CORRECT KEY in the container. Maybe you did not read the question carefully?
Okay here I go again: I create a ssh key pair and store is somewhere on the HOST. I go to github and add the public key ONCE. And I want to create a docker image with the CORRECT PRIVATE KEY in it. That is why I have the following lines in the Dokerfile, as explained in the question: `RUN chmod 600 repo-key && \  
    echo "IdentityFile /selenium/repo-key" >> /etc/ssh/ssh_config && \  
    echo "StrictHostKeyChecking no" >> /etc/ssh/ssh_config`

Comment: Have you tried the solution as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/23411161/2395551

Comment: yes. My question is based on exactly that solution (which does not work for me.) See updated question.....

Answer (score 0):

When cloning a GitHub repo, you still need to specify the right user for establishing that ssh connection: `git`.

So:

```
 git clone git@github.com:User/repo.git
          ^^^^^
```